# Why won't this simple TypeORM query return my ManyToOne property with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

In my database, I have one species record and two cat records

Cat Table

```
id   size   species_id
1    large   5
1    small   5
```

Species Table

```
id 
5
```

```
@Entity('cat')
export class Cat {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  size: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Species)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'species_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  speciesId: string;

}

@Entity('species')
export class Species {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

}

const entity = await this.catRepository.findOneOrFail(catId);
```

the `entity` only returns `{id: catId, size: 'large'}` but does not return the `speciesId` even though there's a species id in the cat record in my database.

I am new to TypeORM and I think one of the things ManyToOne does is to establish FK constraints. Why is the query behavior the way it is and how can I get the species id to return without having to use joins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation I think you are missing 1 extra column in `Cat` entity. Column in which you will store `species_id`, or if you wish to make it accurate, then use singular `specie_id`.

```
@Entity('cat')
export class Cat {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  size: string;

  @Column({type: 'uuid' })
  specie_id: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Species)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'specie_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  species: Species;

}
```

More info you can find in typeorm documentation: https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations

Comment: Thank you. It's not clear in the docs why you need to add an additional id. I suppose the entity annotation just establishes the relationship? But I felt like the join column that gets created also means any orm mapping when querying would be added. Thank you.